Why only test Wronskian at single time t rather than over the entire interval the solution exists
When determining linear independence of solutions to a linear ODE, why do we only need to test the Wronskian at a single time t, rather than over the entire interval in which the solution exists?

that's because the Wronskian is subject to a linear ODE, too, that has no zeros.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wronskian#Application_to_linear_differential_equations
